# Firebase admin.auth().createCustomToken "Letting the Admin SDK discover a service account" approach does not work

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I wrote the following code a cloud function and I am trying to run it on the server side (NOT the client side).

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

export const getJWT = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (context.auth) {
    const token = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(context.auth.uid);
    return { token: token }
  }
  return { token: null };
});
```

It, however, fails with this infamous error.

"Unhandled error { Error: Permission iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob is required to perform this operation on service account projects/-/serviceAccounts/e-groups@appspot.gserviceaccount.com.; Please refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens for more details on how to use and troubleshoot this feature."

The document says there are three approaches.

1. Using a service account JSON file
2. Letting the Admin SDK discover a service account
3. Using a service account ID

I don't like #1 because it's very error prone. Therefore, I am trying to do #2, by just calling admin.initializeApp(), as the documents suggests ("To make use of these signing methods, initialize the SDK with Google Application Default credentials and do not specify a service account ID string").

Why it does not work? Am I missing something?

I am trying to run my code on the server side (not on the emulator). It really does not make sense to take the approach #1, and I much prefer to take #2 method.

### ADDED: Here is the solution!

Because it's very hard to discover exactly what you need to do (even after reading the answer to the duplicate), I am going to describe the step-by-step instruction.

```
 From the Firebase console,
(1) open the setting, 
(2) select Service account tab, 
(3) click "Manage service account permissions"
   notice that "App Engine default service account" is listed
(4) Click the "IAM" on the side bar
(5) Find the "App Engine default service account" and click the Edit button
(6) Click "+ Add Another Role"
(7) Select "Service Account Token Creator" and Save
```

Mostly importantly, **you don't need to handle the dangerous private key file at all** as long as you are running this code on the server side. You can leave the "admin.initializeApp();" as is.

I have wasted a lot of time on this issue (including reading similar questions on the stackoverflow). I wish this answer helps other people.

Comment: You need to give additional permissions to the default service account as described in the dup.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to solve this problem. I was looking for similar questions on the stackoverflow, but there are so many of them and all the ones I found were about the solution #1.